# Authentication within page tab by redirect instead of popup

Tags: authentication, redirect, tabs, facebook-apps

How do I redirect a user who enters a Facebook page tab that runs a Facebook application (instead of a popup to the login page of my app) and then redirect back to page tab?

Comment: why would you ever want to do this?

Comment: as popup is blocked by most browsers

Answer (score 0):

Oh ok,

You need to invoke the popup on user input. If the user clicked something like "Begin Game" or whatever on the landing page, it will not get blocked by popup blockers.

It has to be in an onclick or onmouseup event etc. That will bypass popup blocking.